# What i have to do in java code to kill GoRefQueue Finalizer Thread?

Tags: java, go, gomobile

I have some code, that compiled to `aar` file via `gomobile bind -target=android`

```golang
package counter

var Count = 0

func Increment() {
    Count++
}
```

In Java this code looks like `abstact` class with `getCount` and `increment` methods.

I want to know, how to kill thread created by Go bindings?

I seeing threads via `adb shell` and `ps -T -p [pid]` command. Go thread called `GoRefQueue Finalizer Thread`

Comment: What is the actual question? Elaborate, terminate go thread from where and using what? @Roman

Comment: Question is: What i have to do in java code to kill `GoRefQueue Finalizer Thread`?

Comment: please update the question instead of asking in the comments